# Cocoapod - [!] Unable to find a specification for 'Analytics'

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

I am trying to install pod for Analytics. It installs the pod successfully if I have Analytics pod only in the Podfile. The Podfile is below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TestSDK' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to 
use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!
pod 'Analytics' 

end
```

But if I add private source for another pod in the same Podfile, it gives the above error. The new Podfile is below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'XXXXXX Private Repo XXXXXX'
target 'TestSDK' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to 
use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!
pod 'Analytics' 
pod 'pod_from_the_private_repo' , '=1.0.0'

end
```

The above Podfile successfully install the pod_from_the_private_repo but it shows error for the Analytics only which was installing successfully in the previous case.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration should look something like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# Private pods Spec repository
source 'https://path to your private repo'
# Public spec repository
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectName' do

    # Pods for ProjectName
    pod 'Crashlytics'

    # Private pods

end
```

Comment: `[!] An unexpected version directory `Classes` was encountered for the `/Users/kaishwarya/.cocoapods/repos/segmentio/Analytics` Pod in the `Analytics` repository`

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/BAyC0

I created empty project with exactly the same podfile and everything works fine :)

Comment: Ohh no. my Bad. Thanks so much.